# how to get formating string in Vue.js

Tags: arrays, json, vue.js

Hi i have with this script

```
<div class="description text-left" v-for="item in siteObject.line_info">
<small>{{siteObject.line_info}}</small>
</div>
```

this view:
[ { "lineid": "BN00003054538", "site_site_id": "1961011481", "site_id": "273242829" }]
how can i change this to have view like this:
lineid: BN00003054538 
site_site_id: 1961011481
site_id: 273242829

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `v-for="item in siteObject.line_info"`. So `ìtem` is the current item in `siteObject.line_info` being itterated. Use that `item` to access its properties

```
<div class="description text-left" v-for="item in siteObject.line_info">
    <small>{{item.lineid}}</small>
    <small>{{item.site_site_id}}</small>
    <small>{{item.site_id}}</small>
</div>
```